# Survive Escape from Atlantis: whales and sharks setup

Tags: game-setup, escape-from-atlantis

In  Survive: Escape from Atlantis, are the whales and sharks left out of the map during setup? Do they only appear when flipping "play immediately" whale or shark tile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those creatures only appear when you flip a tile with the aforementioned creature. This is different than the Sea Monsters, that begin on the board at the start of the game.

The nearly [complete rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/59113/stronghold-games-2010-edition-near-final-rules), which a BGG commentor stated have not changed says:

> 1. Set aside the Shark, Whale, and remaining Boat tokens for now.

Comment: I've played a very similar game where dolphins/sharks/octopus/sea monsters all start off the map, and appear as you destroy tiles around Atlantis. I think that one was called Escape From Atlantis though. I guess many people had the same idea for a game!

Comment: I own a copy of Survive, and I posted a link to the rulebook for Survive:Escape from Atlantis, and both games have similar if not identical rules with respect to Whale, Shark, (dolphin) setup. They don't start on the board, you only add them when you flip the appropriate tile.